# Not able to iterate over elements of a particular child in xml

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I am trying to iterate over all the 'Batting' tags in the given xml file using ElementTree using the following code:

```
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET
import requests
f = "https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20cricket.player.profile%20where%20player_id%3D"
s = "2962&diagnostics=true&env=store%3A%2F%2F0TxIGQMQbObzvU4Apia0V0"

ans = f + s
tree = ET.fromstring(requests.get(ans).text)
for x in tree.iter('Batting'):
    matches = x.find('Matches').text
    innings = x.find('Innings').text
    runs = x.find('Runs').text
    average = x.find('Average').text
    print("MATCHES:%d\nINNINGS:%d\nRUNS:%d\nAVERAGE%D\n"%(matches,innings,runs,average))
```

[xml file details](https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/?env=store://0TxIGQMQbObzvU4Apia0V0&_uiFocus=cricket#h=select%20*%20from%20cricket.player.profile%20where%20player_id%3D2962)

When I run the program,it gives an error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "espn.py", line 9, in <module>
    matches = x.find('Matches').text
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

I tried hard but I am not able to figure out why my find query returns empty.

Answer (score 0):

From looking at the YQL Console; 
There are no child nodes of Batting named Matches.

It looks like the Child nodes of Batting is another set of sub-trees just named with a number from 1-20.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/GfsWp.jpg

Try to see if .get(), instead of .text, can retrieve the attribute

https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#finding-interesting-elements